# При инициализации базы данных первичными данными можно ли изображение добавить asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    Какой тип использовать для изображения?
}     


 public static void Initialize(MobileContext context)
            {
                if (!context.Phones.Any())
                {
                    context.Phones.AddRange(
                        new Phone
                        {
                            Name = "iPhone X",
                            Company = "Apple",
                            Price = 600,
                            Image = Как тут быть....
                        }
                    );
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете хранить изображения так:

- локальный путь до изображения (string);
- URL изображения (string);
- и на мой взгляд самый упоротый вариант - переводить картинку в массив
  байт (byte[]), в БД хранить массив байт и расширение исходного
  изображения + еще можно извратиться и хранить base64-строку;

Вообще не нужно хранить изображения в БД, храните пути.